# Handle authentication pop up in wxWebView

Tags: c++, authentication, wxwidgets, okta

I am using `wxWebView` to display `okta login screen`. But when I open login screen in my wxWidgets app, it gives a `authenication pop up` and hence takes time to open actual `login screen`. I want to `close` that `authentication popup` and immediately open login screen. How should I achieve that. In `swift for MAC` same issue is handled by `authentication challenge` : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/handling_an_authentication_challenge.

Is there something like `authentication challenge` to close authentication pop up in `wxWebView` ?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what backend you are using, but I hope [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=remove%20authentication%20popup%20ie&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1) could be helpful.

Comment: I am using Internet Explorer backend which is default in wxWidgets. wxWEBVIEW_BACKEND_IE. link: https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/classwx_web_view.html

Comment: @aromahola, did you see this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/258063/internet-explorer-may-prompt-you-for-a-password and (possibly) this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/892666/you-are-prompted-for-your-user-name-and-password-when-you-open-microso.